# Accessing Subversion commit data externally

Tags: svn

I have need to access subversion data (commit messages, files updated, revision numbers, dates modified, author, etc.) externally. Is this something for some sort of subversion hook or is there a decent third party package for this or some other "best practice" way to approach accessing subversion data externally (and by external I mean from a php/ruby or python script... external to subversion itself)?

Comment: What actual `data` do you mean?

Comment: Yeah, I don't understand what is meant either

Comment: commit messages, files updated, revision numbers, dates modified, author, etc.... I've updated my question to be more explicit.

Comment: @gaoshan88: also define `externally`, please.

Comment: external to subversion itself... say from a custom php/ruby/python script

Comment: @gaoshan88: i've changed my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by externally you mean "without checking out complete repository", then answer is "Yes".

For retrieving all you want you can just use console svn client and perform request right to remote repository, such as:

```
svn cat http://domain/path/to/repo/file.ext
```

Every command can work with either local copy or remote repo.

**UPD**: you've noted that by `externally you mean from python/php/... - so there are bindings to svn from different programming languages. Such as http://pecl.php.net/package/svn - binding for php.

You should find the bindings for appropriate programming language. If there is no such or outdated (is no longer supportable ones) - then you can always just call the same command right from programming language:

```
$result = `svn up`;
```

The sample for php (or `exec()`, or `system()`). You can follow this technique in any language though.

Answer (score 1):

maybe you should take a look into the SVN api

http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.2/svn.developer.html

Comment: I think I posted a link to an outdates version of SVN, just search for the new one, "embedding subversion" is the title of the chapter, which is number 8.